# How to handle page not found by HttpClient?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm making two calls to the same domain but different methods from the <kbd>F12</kbd> in FF. Both are generated fine and give me back a JSON structure.

Then I perform the same calls (same credentials, same everything) using *HttpClient*. The first gives me back the data just as supposed to. The other produces an HTML document the contents of which are rather large but there's text saying:

> You may have landed here because you typed in the wrong adress or because the page has been moved.

The only strange thing I can see is that the status code is 201 and not 200 but that's only saying that the document's been created (we're talking FF, where I can see the status code).

Can something be concluded based on this or is it too vague?

Comment: could you show the code for the call that is not working that would help out for the `HttpClient` call that is not working perhaps you need to do that call via `Asycn calling methods`

Comment: Please show your current code.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Good call. However, I'm already doing the call asynchronously. The problem is with the server, sadly. I also found out the soution - despite the promise of it being GETable method, it was, in fact POSTable. Once I switched to *.PostAsync()* instead of *.GetAsync()*, it started to work. Still - good call. Please post your comment as a reply (and add the thing I said now) so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @GrawCube It won't help you to see the code. The problem is elsewhere, actually. I'm calling a two methods on the service and only one gives me the right stuff back. But you're right principally. Most of the time, code sample is the right way to start.   :)

Comment: Thanks Konrad I am glad that I was able to help lead you to a correct fix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per your request Konrad Viltersten

could you show the code for the call that is not working that would help out for the HttpClient call that is not working perhaps you need to do that call via `.GetAsycn` or `.PostAsync` calling methods